# Is there a channel to provide feedback on the built in applications?

Tags: system-apps

Is there a mechanism to provide feedback to Microsoft (or Nokia) on problems with the built in applications (e.g. 'People' or 'Podcasts').

I can reliably crash some of the built in apps and would like to provide the feedback, or is the telemetry collected automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application crashes automatically send telemetry back to Microsoft that developers can log in to their developer portal, and get hold of the stack trace that failed. Microsoft [has said in the past](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/e7/feedback-and-engineering-windows-7) that they concentrate on the most common failure points first, when talking about Windows 7 it was said:

> The telemetry really helps us focus on the benefit of the change — fixing a bug that represents thousands of customers, a widely used device, or broadly used third party software has a much bigger impact than a bug that only a few people, lower volume device, or less used software product might address. With this data we can more precisely evaluate benefit of changes.

I would expect them to take a similar approach with their Windows Phone apps, as I would expect other third party developers.